# Prepared statement and setString

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a problem with `setString`. When I add `%` to the parameter in the `setString`, it works even if I don't write anything. However, when I remove it it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
String Id= User1.getText().toString();
String Passwords = Pass.getText().toString();


btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
         String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id LIKE ? AND pass LIKE ? ";
            try {
                if (connect != null) {
                   PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                statement.setString(1, Id );  //  statement.setString(1 ,"%" + Id + "%");
               statement.setString(2 ,Passwords);//  statement.setString(2 ,"%" + Passwords + "%");
                   r = statement.executeQuery();
                    if (r.next()){

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setClass(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                            }
                     else {
                        message = "Error";
                        info.setText(message);
                    }

                } else {
                    message = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                    info.setText(message);
                }


            } catch (SQLException e) {
                etat = false;
                message = "Got an exception!";
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }


    }});  }
```

P.S: I get no errors

Comment: Could it be a character encoding issue?

Comment: @Maurice I have no idea why it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your SQL query is begging for like Syntax.

If you do not want to use `%%`, Pass the direct String and change LIKE query to `=` Query.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id = ? AND pass = ?
```

But checking username and password with like operator is a terrible idea. Always check that they are equals or not.

Comment: I have tried before to replace Like by = , but it doesn't work

Comment: can you paste the final sql query formed ?

Comment: @Mimi then you have a problem in your data or inputs check them and make sure you are using the correct information, from what you share we understand  that this is the right answer of your problem

Comment: @SURESH     String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id = ? AND pass = ? ";
            try {
                if (connect != null) {
                   PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                    statement.setString(1 ,Id );
                    statement.setString(2 ,Passwords );
                   r = statement.executeQuery();

Comment: Is 'TABLE'  an allowed name for a table?

Comment: @FredyFischer It is not. Looks like OP hidden his table table name.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Can you help me further? I am still blocked